# We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api, server-error

I have several scripts bound to a spreadsheet that create 14 folders containing a total of about 240 google sheets.  The original sheet that the scripts are bound to contains about 34000 rows of data that are divided among the newly created sheets.  While I was working on it I frequently deleted and recreated all the folders and sheets and it worked fine.  Yesterday, as I'm ready to do my final run and create the spreadsheets that will be shared and used I started getting "We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again".  I tried again this morning and got the same thing.

I have tried a different browser. I created a new sheet and copied the scripts over.  Then I deleted all but a single script that creates the folders and commented out all of the code in that except 3 lines that get the current spreadsheet and write out a message but I'm still getting the error.
The link to my stripped down, barely there but still not working spreadsheet is https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18_FjSpuGONEVzNZu5Ta8hm0YopsdlZlPRRAV7cx5VTE/edit#gid=1999362590

I'm thinking it may have something to do with my user account, or having reached some quotas.  Is there any way to check that?

Comment: The linked file was moved to the owner trash.

Answer (score 2):

If you reach a quota when using a Google App Script, it should notify you with a [specific exception](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas).  The quotas themselves can be seen [here](https://docs.google.com/macros/dashboard).

Have you tried removing the permissions for the script and authorising it again?  I have had this issue previously and this resolved my problem (although, I accept it will not always resolve this problem...).

I would post the link, but I don't have enough reputation to post more than 2 links... Google "See apps connected to my Google account".

Comment: Paul's answer fixed this for me, though my details might be useful. I developed a series of scripts that were called each other and executed quite frequently. At some point during development an error caused a recursive urlfetch, which I fixed within a few minutes. Ever since then I had this problem. Deauthorizing and then reauthorizing appears to have cleared something up.